# Page.find() not working in a partial template

Tags: grav

Here's partial template:

```
<a href="{{ url('videos') }}">
    <h6 class="borbottom text-uppercase"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> Serke TV</h6>
</a>

{% for p in page.find('/videos').children if p != page %}
  <h3>{{ p.title }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

I have videos route, that displays all his child elements. I want to display all videos (child elements) in a block as partial template, which i certain pages.

However that `page.find()` nor `page.collection('videos')` not working for me.

Comment: What is this partial template in? Why not use a collections setup similar to the blog in the example template?

Comment: `page.find()` should only be able to pull up subpages, right? I think you need to run that against pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`page` object](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars#page-object) which is the current page. So you are looking for `videos` pages in the current page.

You need to use [`pages` object](https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/theme-vars#pages-object) to be able to search in all pages. You can see the functions you can use with this object [here](https://learn.getgrav.org/api#class-grav-common-page-pages)